# Find a set of vectors with special property

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given vectors $\alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_{m}$ in an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, such
that $(\alpha_i, \alpha_j) \leq 0$ for $i\neq j$ and $(a_i,a_i)\neq 0$. Find the maximum value of $m$.

---

The answer is $2n$.
It's easy to know $m\geq 2n$. Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be the orthonormal basis of $V$. And take $e_{n+i}=-e_i.$ Then $(e_i,e_j)\leq 0,i\neq j.$
But I don't know how to show $m\leq 2n.$

Comment: Are the $\alpha_j$ linear independent, or at least $\not=0$? Otherwise $m > 2n$ is possible.

Comment: @Gerd $a_i\neq 0.$

Comment: Thinking about half-spaces tells you that your solution is in fact optimal — of course you can rotate the picture, but if you do anything other than what you've done, you won't even get to $2n$. (If you choose a vector in the interior of a half-space rather than on its boundary, you will run out of room before you're done.) Try this with $n=2$ to see it concretely. I don't have an elegant proof yet.

Comment: @TedShifrin Given an ordered set of vectors $(e_k)_{k=1}^m$, maybe recursively project $e_\ell$ to the orthogonal complement of the span of $(e_k)_{k=1}^{\ell-1}$ and show the resulting union of half spaces contains the "original" union...? Geometrically that seems to capture low-dimensional intuition, but I haven't checked that this works algebraically.

Comment: @Park Can you unaccept my answer please, it is not correct.

Comment: @copper.hat Why? Your answer is correct.

Comment: No, I made a mistake, the $b_k$ I defined so not satisfy the $\le 0$, I made a silly mistake in my computations last night. It did seem too easy :-(.

Comment: @copper.hat Without loss of generality, we may assume $(\alpha_i,\alpha_i)=1.$ If $\alpha_2=k_1\alpha_1+b_2,\alpha_3=k_2\alpha_1+b_3$ where $b_i\in \alpha_1^\perp,$ then $(\alpha_2,\alpha_3)=k_1k_2+(b_1,b_2)\leq 0$ which implies $(b_1,b_2)\leq -k_1k_2\leq 0$ since $k_i\leq 0.$

Comment: @Park yeah, you are correct. I did a quick computation this morning but made a mistake and asked a mod to delete the answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

Let us prove by induction that there are at most $2n$ such vectors. First for a vector $v$, we define the vector $v'$ as the vector without the first coordinate. For example, $v=(1,2,3)$, then $v'=(2,3)$.

Now suppose we have $k$ nonzero vectors $v_{1},\cdots,v_{k}$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$ with pairwise non-positive inner product. We can assume $v_{1}=(1,0,\cdots,0)$. Then $v_{2},\cdots,v_{k}$ have non-positive first coordinate, so $v_{2}',\cdots,v_{k}'\in \Bbb{R}^{n-1}$ also have pairwise nonpositive inner product (otherwise if $\langle v_{i}',v_{j}'\rangle> 0$, then $\langle v_{i},v_{j}\rangle=$ (product of the first coordinates of $v_{i}$ and $v_{j}$)+$\langle v_{i}',v_{j}'\rangle>0$). However, some $v_{i}'$ here can be zero, so we assume $A\subseteq \{v_{2}',\cdots,v_{k}'\}$ is the set of all nonzero vectors.

Thus, we can use the induction hypothesis, we know $A$ has at most $2n-2$ cardinality. Since there is no $v_{i}, v_{j}$ such that $v_{i}'=v_{j}'$ (because $\langle v_{i}',v_{j}'\rangle\leq 0$ as we showed), there are at most $2n-2$ vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ which are nonzero after deleting the first coordinate.

We also have at most 2 vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ which are zero after deleting the first coordinate. The first one is $v_{1}$, the second one is $v_{0}=(a,0,\cdots, 0)$ with $a<0$. If we have the third one $t=(b,0,\cdots, 0)$,  then one of $\langle t,v_{1}\rangle$, $\langle t,v_{0}\rangle$ is positive.

Finally in total there are at most $2n-2+2=2n$ vectors.

Comment: I don’t follow the fourth and fifth sentences. Can you improve your exposition?

Comment: @TedShifrin Edited.

Comment: Thanks. Other than to make the induction statement clear from the outset, I can make no suggestions to improve your argument,

Answer (score 3):

I seem to be unable to undelete my previous answer.

It is straightforward to see that for $n=1$ there at at most $2n$ vectors satisfying the conditions.

Suppose it is true for $1,..,n$.
Further, suppose we have $a_1,...,a_{2(n+1)+1}$ points in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that satisfy the conditions. This will lead to a contradiction.

For $j \ge 2$ we can write $a_j = \lambda_j a_1 + b_j$, where $b_j \bot a_1$. Since $\langle a_j, a_1 \rangle \le 0$, we see that $\lambda_j \le 0$.
Also, $\langle a_i, a_j \rangle = \lambda_i \lambda_j \|a_1\|^2+\langle b_i, b_j \rangle$, and so $\langle b_i, b_j \rangle \le 0$ for $i \neq j$.
Note that the $b_j $ all lie in the $n-1$ dimensional subspace $a_1^\bot$.

The inductive hypothesis shows that $b_2,...,b_{2(n+1)+1}$ (there are $2n+2$ elements) must have at least
two zero elements, without loss of generality suppose $b_2,b_3$ are zero. Then
$a_2 = \mu_2 a_1, a_3 = \mu_3 a_1$ for some non zero $\mu_2,\mu_3$ and a pair of the points $a_1,a_2,a_3$ must violate the non positive inner product condition.