# When does a set of vectors positively span $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inner-products

I remember reading an answer to a question similar to this one in MSE or MO, but I can't find it. I am looking for a proof or a reference.

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a set of vectors such that no nonzero $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies that for all $a\in A$, $\langle v,a\rangle\geq0$. Is every vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ a positive linear combination of vectors of $A$ (that is, a sum $\sum_{i=1}^nk_ia_i$, with $k_i\geq0, a_i\in A$)? Also, can we always find a subset of $n+1$ elements of $A$ which satisfies the same condition?

If someone finds better tags for this question please add them.

Edit: As Andrew D. Hwang says in the comments, the second question about a subset of $n+1$ elements of $A$ is not necessarily true: we can just consider $A$ to be the union of the usual basis of vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and their opposites.

Comment: I think you want a *strict* inequality for $\langle v, a \rangle \geq 0$ or else the zero-vector will always be some $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies the weak inequality $\forall a$.

Comment: (That or you meant $v \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$). Also, I think that you mean to ask whether there *exists at least one* positive linear combination of $A$ for every vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Because $A$ will surely be a redundant basis and thus have infinite ways to express any vector on it.

Comment: Any positive  linear combination $v$ of vectors from $A$ would have $\langle v, v \rangle < 0.$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545096/find-a-set-of-vectors-with-special-property/ was recently asked, and is similar...? <> Whether or not that's useful, could you please confirm whether _positive_ means _strictly positive_ or _non-negative_, and whether _positive linear combination_ means _some_ coefficient is "positive"?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will update the question to make it clearer

Comment: Your first condition has a "double negative" so it's confusing. You should instead write every non-zero $v$ satisfies $\langle v ,a \rangle <0  $. Moreover, this isn't even possible. If $v \neq 0$ and $\langle v,a \rangle < 0 $, then $-v \neq 0$ and $\langle -v, a\rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: @DionelJaime I think I see how a misunderstanding is possible, I will change the order of that sentence so it's clearer

Comment: How did *positive* turn into $k_i\le 0$?

Comment: Oops I wrote leq instead of geq and didn't bother to check. But don't worry, at some point in the future I am positive ($\leq0$) that the question won't contain any more mistakes

Comment: The answer to second part (Is there a subset of $(n+1)$ elements with the same property?) is generally _no_ for $n > 1$: If $A$ is the $2n$-element set comprising the standard basis vectors and their negatives, then the set of positive linear combinations of every proper subset is contained in a closed half-space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days I remembered this question and found an easy positive answer: it is enough to prove that, if $A$ is as in the question, then the convex closure $B$ of $A$ contains an open neighborhood of $0$.

Suppose that is not the case. The set $B$ is convex and $0$ is not in its interior, so there are two cases:

- $0$ is in the boundary of $B$. Then there is a [supporting hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane) of $B$ at $0$ given by $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n;\langle x,v\rangle=0\}$ for some $v$, which contradicts the statement of the question.
- $0$ is not in the boundary of $B$. We still have [supporting hyperplanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem#Statements_and_proof) in this case, so a similar reasoning applies.